# What array size should I use to print glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)?

Tags: opengl

I used this and it crashed on some system:

```
char s[8192]
```

I just need to print it to the console and then save it to a file as  log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a pointer instead of this `char s[8192]` if size is doubtful.
I recommend you to do this kind of thing:

```
char* extensionList = (char*)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

[Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103013148/http://rainwarrior.thenoos.net/dragon/sdl_glsl.html)